# Using Selenium WebDriver with RSpec, how to test whether Chrome has installed an extension successfully?

Tags: rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am using Selenium WebDriver with ChromeDriver to install an extension as follows:

```
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, args: ["--load-extension=#{path_to_extension}"]
```

I can observe visually that the extension is indeed installed successfully.

However, I want to write an assertion for the same, something like the following:

```
expect { browser.extension_is_intalled(extension_id) }.to be_true
```

How do I do that?

Comment: It's [impossible with Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768425/how-to-access-firefox-extension-i-added-in-selenium-webdriver), not a big chance it's different with Chrome