# How to configure Firefox extension in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox extension and testing how it works using Selenium. This is the setup:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void startDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
    final URL seleniumUrl = new URL("http://selenium:4444/wd/hub");

    final FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
    final File extension = new File(Paths.get(currentPath.toString(), "insecure-links-highlighter.xpi").toString());
    profile.addExtension(extension);

    final FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProfile(profile);

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumUrl, options);
}
```

**How do I change the configuration of the extension to something other than the default?** The add-on configuration options don't appear in about:config (even after changing to non-default values), so I'm not sure if they can even be configured like built-in Firefox settings.

So far I've tried `profile.setPreference` with these keys:

```
extensions.name-of-extension.nameOfConfigurationVariable
extensions.{UUID-of-extension}.nameOfConfigurationVariable
extensions.webextensions.{UUID-of-extension}.nameOfConfigurationVariable
```

I've seen [answers mentioning Firebug configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16882491/96588), but a lot of things have changed since they were made. Based on that I guess a question which might also lead somewhere useful would be where WebExtensions' configuration is stored.

Comment: I think firefox developer edition has to be used now for xpinstall.signatures to work.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I am using developer edition. I already have a working test suite for this extension, I just need to test that it works when changing a setting.